# Merge two dataframes creating empty rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting a weird problem after hours of trying to figure out how to merge correcting.

Assuming two dataframes:

```
financials_Balance_Sheet_yearly.loc[financials_Balance_Sheet_yearly.ticker == 'AAPL.US']
    Unnamed: 0  ticker  date    filing_date currency_symbol totalassets intangibleassets    earningassets   othercurrentassets  totalliab   totalstockholderequity  deferredlongtermliab    othercurrentliab    commonstock retainedearnings    otherliab   goodwill    otherassets cash    totalcurrentliabilities shorttermdebt   shortlongtermdebt   shortlongtermdebttotal  otherstockholderequity  propertyplantequipment  totalcurrentassets  longterminvestments nettangibleassets   shortterminvestments    netreceivables  longtermdebt    inventory   accountspayable totalpermanentequity    noncontrollinginterestinconsolidatedentity  temporaryequityredeemablenoncontrollinginterests    accumulatedothercomprehensiveincome additionalpaidincapital commonstocktotalequity  preferredstocktotalequity   retainedearningstotalequity treasurystock   accumulatedamortization noncurrrentassetsother  deferredlongtermassetcharges    noncurrentassetstotal   capitalleaseobligations longtermdebttotal   noncurrentliabilitiesother  noncurrentliabilitiestotal  negativegoodwill    warrants    preferredstockredeemable    capitalsurpluse liabilitiesandstockholdersequity    cashandshortterminvestments propertyplantandequipmentgross  accumulateddepreciation commonstocksharesoutstanding    networkingcapital   netdebt netinvestedcapital  freecashflow    changeinworkingcapital
128270  128270  AAPL.US 2019-09-30  2019-10-31  USD 3.385160e+11    NaN NaN 1.235200e+10    2.480280e+11    9.048800e+10    NaN 4.324200e+10    4.517400e+10    4.589800e+10    5.050300e+10    NaN 3.297800e+10    4.884400e+10    1.057180e+11    1.624000e+10    1.624000e+10    1.080470e+11    -5.840000e+08   3.737800e+10    1.628190e+11    1.053410e+11    9.048800e+10    5.171300e+10    4.580400e+10    9.180700e+10    4.106000e+09    4.623600e+10    NaN NaN NaN -5.840000e+08   NaN 4.517400e+10    NaN 4.589800e+10    NaN NaN 3.297800e+10    NaN 1.756970e+11    NaN 9.180700e+10    5.050300e+10    1.423100e+11    NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.385160e+11    1.005570e+11    3.737800e+10    NaN 1.859565e+10    5.710100e+10    5.920300e+10    1.985350e+11    NaN NaN
128288  128288  AAPL.US 2018-09-30  2018-11-05  USD 3.657250e+11    NaN NaN 1.208700e+10    2.585780e+11    1.071470e+11    2.797000e+09    4.023000e+10    4.020100e+10    7.040000e+10    4.891400e+10    NaN 2.228300e+10    2.591300e+10    1.168660e+11    2.074800e+10    2.074800e+10    1.144830e+11    -3.454000e+09   4.130400e+10    1.313390e+11    1.707990e+11    1.071470e+11    4.038800e+10    4.899500e+10    9.373500e+10    3.956000e+09    5.588800e+10    NaN NaN NaN -3.454000e+09   NaN 4.020100e+10    NaN 7.040000e+10    NaN NaN 2.228300e+10    NaN 2.343860e+11    NaN 9.373500e+10    4.518000e+10    1.417120e+11    NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.657250e+11    6.630100e+10    4.130400e+10    NaN 2.000044e+10    1.447300e+10    8.857000e+10    2.216300e+11    NaN NaN
128311  128311  AAPL.US 2017-09-30  2017-11-03  USD 3.753190e+11    2.298000e+09    NaN 1.393600e+10    2.412720e+11    1.340470e+11    2.836000e+09    7.548000e+09    3.586700e+10    9.833000e+10    4.325100e+10    5.717000e+09    1.817700e+10    2.028900e+10    1.008140e+11    1.847300e+10    1.847300e+10    1.156800e+11    -1.500000e+08   3.378300e+10    1.286450e+11    1.947140e+11    1.260320e+11    5.389200e+10    3.567300e+10    9.720700e+10    4.855000e+09    7.479300e+10    0.0 0.0 0.0 -1.500000e+08   0.0 3.586700e+10    0.0 9.833000e+10    0.0 NaN 1.016200e+10    NaN 2.466740e+11    NaN 9.720700e+10    4.041500e+10    1.404580e+11    NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.753190e+11    7.418100e+10    3.378300e+10    NaN 2.100677e+10    2.783100e+10    9.539100e+10    2.497270e+11    NaN NaN
128337  128337  AAPL.US 2016-09-30  2016-10-26  USD 3.216860e+11    3.206000e+09    NaN 8.283000e+09    1.934370e+11    1.282490e+11    2.930000e+09    8.080000e+09    3.125100e+10    9.636400e+10    3.900400e+10    5.414000e+09    8.757000e+09    2.048400e+10    7.900600e+10    1.160500e+10    1.160500e+10    8.703200e+10    6.340000e+08    2.701000e+10    1.068690e+11    1.704300e+11    1.196290e+11    4.667100e+10    1.575400e+10    7.542700e+10    2.132000e+09    5.932100e+10    NaN NaN NaN 6.340000e+08    NaN 3.125100e+10    NaN 9.636400e+10    NaN NaN -1.726200e+10   NaN 2.148170e+11    NaN 7.542700e+10    3.607400e+10    1.144310e+11    NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.216860e+11    6.715500e+10    2.701000e+10    NaN 2.200112e+10    NaN 6.654800e+10    NaN NaN NaN
128386  128386  AAPL.US 2014-09-30  2014-10-27  USD 2.318390e+11    4.142000e+09    NaN 9.806000e+09    1.202920e+11    1.115470e+11    3.031000e+09    8.491000e+09    2.331300e+10    8.715200e+10    7.598000e+09    4.616000e+09    3.764000e+09    1.384400e+10    6.344800e+10    6.308000e+09    3.529500e+10    3.529500e+10    1.082000e+09    2.062400e+10    6.853100e+10    1.301620e+11    1.027890e+11    1.123300e+10    1.746000e+10    2.898700e+10    2.111000e+09    4.864900e+10    0.0 0.0 0.0 1.082000e+09    0.0 2.331300e+10    0.0 8.715200e+10    0.0 NaN -1.649500e+10   NaN 1.633080e+11    NaN 2.898700e+10    2.482600e+10    5.684400e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.318390e+11    2.507700e+10    2.062400e+10    NaN 2.449065e+10    NaN 2.145100e+10    NaN NaN NaN
128413  128413  AAPL.US 2013-09-30  2013-10-30  USD 2.070000e+11    4.179000e+09    NaN 6.882000e+09    8.345100e+10    1.235490e+11    2.625000e+09    7.435000e+09    1.976400e+10    1.042560e+11    6.344000e+09    1.577000e+09    5.146000e+09    1.425900e+10    4.365800e+10    NaN NaN 1.696000e+10    -4.710000e+08   1.659700e+10    7.328600e+10    1.062150e+11    1.177930e+11    2.628700e+10    1.310200e+10    1.696000e+10    1.764000e+09    3.622300e+10    0.0 0.0 0.0 -4.710000e+08   0.0 1.976400e+10    0.0 1.042560e+11    0.0 NaN -1.134300e+10   NaN 1.337140e+11    NaN 1.696000e+10    2.020800e+10    3.979300e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.070000e+11    4.054600e+10    1.659700e+10    NaN 2.608654e+10    NaN 2.701000e+09    NaN NaN NaN
128450  128450  AAPL.US 2012-09-30  2012-10-31  USD 1.760640e+11    4.224000e+09    NaN 6.458000e+09    5.785400e+10    1.182100e+11    2.648000e+09    5.953000e+09    1.642200e+10    1.012890e+11    5.465000e+09    1.135000e+09    5.478000e+09    1.074600e+10    3.854200e+10    NaN NaN NaN 4.990000e+08    1.545200e+10    5.765300e+10    9.212200e+10    1.128510e+11    1.838300e+10    1.093000e+10    0.000000e+00    7.910000e+08    3.258900e+10    0.0 0.0 0.0 4.990000e+08    0.0 1.642200e+10    0.0 1.012890e+11    0.0 NaN -8.369000e+09   NaN 1.184110e+11    NaN NaN 1.666400e+10    1.931200e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.760640e+11    2.912900e+10    1.545200e+10    NaN 2.646994e+10    NaN -1.074600e+10   NaN NaN NaN
128453  128453  AAPL.US 2011-09-30  2011-10-26  USD 1.163710e+11    3.536000e+09    NaN 4.529000e+09    3.975600e+10    7.661500e+10    1.686000e+09    4.091000e+09    1.333100e+10    6.284100e+10    3.627000e+09    8.960000e+08    3.556000e+09    9.815000e+09    2.797000e+10    NaN NaN NaN 4.430000e+08    7.777000e+09    4.498800e+10    5.561800e+10    7.218300e+10    1.613700e+10    5.369000e+09    0.000000e+00    7.760000e+08    2.387900e+10    0.0 0.0 0.0 4.430000e+08    0.0 1.333100e+10    0.0 6.284100e+10    0.0 NaN -4.603000e+09   NaN 7.138300e+10    NaN NaN 1.010000e+10    1.178600e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.163710e+11    2.595200e+10    7.777000e+09    NaN 2.622606e+10    NaN -9.815000e+09   NaN NaN NaN
128514  128514  AAPL.US 2010-09-30  2010-10-27  USD 7.518300e+10    3.420000e+08    NaN 3.447000e+09    2.739200e+10    4.779100e+10    1.139000e+09    2.984000e+09    1.066800e+10    3.716900e+10    2.370000e+09    7.410000e+08    2.263000e+09    1.126100e+10    2.072200e+10    NaN NaN NaN -4.600000e+07   4.768000e+09    4.167800e+10    2.539100e+10    4.670800e+10    1.435900e+10    5.510000e+09    0.000000e+00    1.051000e+09    1.773800e+10    0.0 0.0 0.0 -4.600000e+07   0.0 1.066800e+10    0.0 3.716900e+10    0.0 NaN -2.037000e+09   NaN 3.350500e+10    NaN NaN 5.531000e+09    6.670000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.518300e+10    2.562000e+10    4.768000e+09    NaN 2.589194e+10    NaN -1.126100e+10   NaN NaN NaN
128550  128550  AAPL.US 2008-09-30  2008-11-05  USD 3.957200e+10    3.520000e+08    NaN 4.987000e+09    1.854200e+10    2.103000e+10    NaN 8.572000e+09    7.177000e+09    1.384500e+10    3.775000e+09    2.070000e+08    1.868000e+09    1.187500e+10    1.409200e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.455000e+09    3.469000e+10    NaN NaN 1.261500e+10    2.422000e+09    NaN 5.090000e+08    5.520000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 8.000000e+06    NaN 7.177000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.193000e+09    NaN 4.882000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 4.450000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.957200e+10    NaN 2.455000e+09    NaN 2.525989e+10    NaN -1.187500e+10   NaN NaN NaN
128581  128581  AAPL.US 2006-09-30  2006-12-29  USD 1.720500e+10    1.390000e+08    NaN 1.284000e+09    7.221000e+09    9.984000e+09    NaN 3.081000e+09    4.355000e+09    5.607000e+09    3.690000e+08    3.800000e+07    1.217000e+09    6.392000e+09    6.471000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.281000e+09    1.450900e+10    NaN NaN 3.718000e+09    1.252000e+09    NaN 2.700000e+08    3.390000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 2.200000e+07    NaN 4.355000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.238000e+09    NaN 2.696000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 7.500000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.720500e+10    NaN 1.281000e+09    NaN 2.457073e+10    NaN -6.392000e+09   NaN NaN NaN
128588  128588  AAPL.US 2005-09-30  2005-12-01  USD 1.155100e+10    6.500000e+07    NaN 5.620000e+08    4.085000e+09    7.466000e+09    NaN 1.705000e+09    3.521000e+09    4.005000e+09    2.930000e+08    6.900000e+07    3.000000e+08    3.491000e+09    3.484000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.170000e+08    1.030000e+10    NaN NaN 4.770000e+09    8.950000e+08    NaN 1.650000e+08    1.779000e+09    NaN NaN NaN -6.640000e+08   NaN 3.521000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN -8.000000e+06   NaN 1.251000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 6.010000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.155100e+10    NaN 8.170000e+08    NaN 2.398984e+10    NaN -3.491000e+09   NaN NaN NaN
128610  128610  AAPL.US 2004-09-30  2004-12-03  USD 8.050000e+09    4.200000e+07    NaN 4.400000e+08    2.974000e+09    5.076000e+09    NaN 1.229000e+09    2.514000e+09    2.670000e+09    2.940000e+08    8.000000e+07    1.896000e+08    2.969000e+09    2.680000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.070000e+08    7.055000e+09    NaN NaN 2.495000e+09    7.740000e+08    NaN 1.010000e+08    1.451000e+09    NaN NaN NaN -1.500000e+07   NaN 2.514000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN -1.280000e+08   NaN 9.950000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 2.940000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.050000e+09    NaN 7.070000e+08    NaN 2.168942e+10    NaN -2.969000e+09   NaN NaN NaN
128621  128621  AAPL.US 2002-09-30  2002-12-19  USD 6.298000e+09    3.400000e+07    NaN 4.410000e+08    2.203000e+09    4.095000e+09    NaN 7.470000e+08    1.826000e+09    2.325000e+09    NaN 8.500000e+07    1.700000e+08    2.252000e+09    1.658000e+09    NaN NaN 3.160000e+08    NaN 6.210000e+08    5.388000e+09    NaN NaN 2.085000e+09    5.650000e+08    3.160000e+08    4.500000e+07    9.110000e+08    NaN NaN NaN -5.600000e+07   NaN 1.826000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN -9.800000e+07   NaN 9.100000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 5.450000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 6.298000e+09    NaN 6.210000e+08    NaN 2.025996e+10    NaN -1.936000e+09   NaN NaN NaN
128670  128670  AAPL.US 2001-09-30  2001-12-21  USD 6.021000e+09    1.000000e+07    NaN 3.300000e+08    2.101000e+09    3.920000e+09    NaN 7.170000e+08    1.693000e+09    2.260000e+09    NaN 6.600000e+07    3.140000e+08    2.310000e+09    1.518000e+09    NaN NaN 3.170000e+08    NaN 5.640000e+08    5.143000e+09    NaN NaN 2.026000e+09    4.660000e+08    3.170000e+08    1.100000e+07    8.010000e+08    NaN NaN NaN -3.300000e+07   NaN 1.693000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN -1.560000e+08   NaN 8.780000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 5.830000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 6.021000e+09    NaN 5.640000e+08    NaN 1.935433e+10    NaN -1.993000e+09   NaN NaN NaN
128684  128684  AAPL.US 1999-09-30  1999-12-22  NaN 5.161000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 2.057000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.499000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.326000e+09    1.549000e+09    NaN NaN 3.000000e+08    NaN NaN 4.285000e+09    NaN NaN 1.900000e+09    6.810000e+08    NaN 2.000000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.060000e+08    NaN 1.349000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.100000e+07    NaN 8.760000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 5.080000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.161000e+09    NaN 3.180000e+08    NaN 1.950637e+10    NaN -1.026000e+09   NaN NaN NaN
128694  128694  AAPL.US 2000-09-30  2000-12-14  USD 6.803000e+09    NaN NaN 4.140000e+08    2.696000e+09    4.107000e+09    NaN 7.760000e+08    1.502000e+09    2.285000e+09    NaN NaN 1.063000e+09    1.191000e+09    1.933000e+09    NaN NaN 3.000000e+08    NaN 3.130000e+08    5.427000e+09    NaN NaN 2.836000e+09    9.530000e+08    3.000000e+08    3.300000e+07    1.157000e+09    NaN NaN NaN -3.870000e+08   NaN 1.502000e+09    76000000.0  NaN NaN NaN 1.063000e+09    NaN 1.376000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 7.630000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 6.803000e+09    NaN 3.130000e+08    NaN 2.017814e+10    NaN -8.910000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
128698  128698  AAPL.US 1998-09-30  1998-09-25  NaN 4.289000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 2.647000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.980000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 1.481000e+09    1.520000e+09    NaN NaN 9.540000e+08    NaN NaN 3.698000e+09    NaN NaN 8.190000e+08    9.550000e+08    NaN 7.800000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN -3.900000e+07   NaN 6.330000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.000000e+07    NaN 5.910000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 1.127000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.289000e+09    NaN 3.480000e+08    NaN 1.880670e+10    NaN -5.270000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
128713  128713  AAPL.US 1996-09-30  1996-12-19  NaN 5.364000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 3.306000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.634000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.552000e+09    2.003000e+09    1.860000e+08    NaN 1.135000e+09    NaN NaN 4.515000e+09    NaN NaN 1.930000e+08    1.496000e+09    NaN 6.620000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -3.000000e+07   NaN 4.390000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -1.030000e+08   NaN 8.490000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 1.303000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.364000e+09    NaN 5.980000e+08    NaN 1.385821e+10    NaN -4.170000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
128720  128720  AAPL.US 1994-09-30  1994-12-13  NaN 5.302746e+09    NaN NaN NaN 2.919445e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.096206e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.203488e+09    1.944305e+09    2.922000e+08    NaN 5.962000e+08    NaN NaN 4.476452e+09    NaN NaN 5.436800e+07    1.581347e+09    NaN 1.088434e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN -7.850880e+08   NaN 2.979290e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.591940e+08    NaN 8.262940e+08    NaN NaN NaN 9.751400e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.302746e+09    NaN 6.671000e+08    NaN 1.330672e+10    NaN -6.072880e+08   NaN NaN NaN
128748  128748  AAPL.US 1992-09-30  1992-09-30  NaN 4.223700e+09    NaN NaN NaN 2.036300e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.904500e+09    NaN NaN NaN 4.986000e+08    1.425500e+09    1.845000e+08    NaN 1.845000e+08    NaN NaN 3.558400e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.087200e+09    NaN 5.801000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -6.734000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.031000e+08    NaN 6.653000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 6.108000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.223700e+09    NaN 4.622000e+08    NaN 1.368774e+10    NaN -3.141000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
128753  128753  AAPL.US 1991-09-30  1991-09-30  NaN 3.493600e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.726900e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.492000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 6.041000e+08    1.217100e+09    1.486000e+08    NaN 1.486000e+08    NaN NaN 2.863600e+09    NaN NaN NaN 9.072000e+08    NaN 6.717000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -5.880000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.820000e+08    NaN 6.300000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 5.098000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.493600e+09    NaN 4.480000e+08    NaN 1.344868e+10    NaN -4.555000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
128765  128765  AAPL.US 1990-09-30  1990-09-30  NaN 2.975700e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.528900e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.312200e+09    NaN NaN NaN 3.747000e+08    1.027000e+09    1.226000e+08    NaN 1.226000e+08    NaN NaN 2.403300e+09    NaN NaN NaN 7.619000e+08    NaN 3.555000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -4.467000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.742000e+08    NaN 5.724000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 5.019000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.975700e+09    NaN 3.982000e+08    NaN 1.407111e+10    NaN -2.521000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
128805  128805  AAPL.US 1988-09-30  1988-09-30  NaN 2.082100e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.078700e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.765000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 5.457000e+08    8.271000e+08    1.279000e+08    NaN 3.150000e+08    NaN NaN 1.783000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 6.388000e+08    NaN 4.615000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -2.130000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 9.170000e+07    NaN 2.991000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 2.516000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.082100e+09    NaN 2.074000e+08    NaN 1.455636e+10    NaN -2.307000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
128810  128810  AAPL.US 1989-09-30  1989-09-30  NaN 2.743900e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.258200e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.175900e+09    NaN NaN NaN 4.383000e+08    8.953000e+08    5.680000e+07    NaN 5.680000e+07    NaN NaN 2.294400e+09    NaN NaN NaN 7.928000e+08    NaN 4.754000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -3.091000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.153000e+08    NaN 4.495000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 3.629000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.743900e+09    NaN 3.342000e+08    NaN 1.436384e+10    NaN -3.815000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
128846  128846  AAPL.US 1985-09-30  1985-09-30  NaN 9.362000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 3.857000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.203000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 3.370000e+08    2.954000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.221000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 2.202000e+08    NaN 1.670000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -8.520000e+07   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.370000e+07    NaN 1.141000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 9.030000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN 9.362000e+08    NaN 9.040000e+07    NaN 1.370880e+10    NaN -3.370000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
145183  145183  AAPL.US 1993-09-30  1993-09-30  NaN 5.171400e+09    NaN NaN NaN 3.145000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.842600e+09    NaN NaN NaN 6.764000e+08    2.515200e+09    8.232000e+08    NaN 8.232000e+08    NaN NaN 4.338400e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.381900e+09    NaN 1.506600e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN -7.531000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.735000e+08    NaN 8.330000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 6.298000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.171400e+09    NaN 6.595000e+08    NaN 1.310703e+10    NaN 1.468000e+08    NaN NaN NaN
193123  193123  AAPL.US 1986-09-30  1986-09-30  NaN 1.160100e+09    NaN NaN NaN 4.660000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.743000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 5.762000e+08    3.285000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.040900e+09    NaN NaN NaN 2.631000e+08    NaN 1.087000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -1.147000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.190000e+07    NaN 1.192000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 1.375000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.160100e+09    NaN 1.073000e+08    NaN 1.437333e+10    NaN -5.762000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
214345  214345  AAPL.US 1997-09-30  1997-12-05  NaN 4.233000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 3.033000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.890000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 1.230000e+09    1.818000e+09    2.500000e+07    NaN 9.760000e+08    NaN NaN 3.424000e+09    NaN NaN 2.290000e+08    1.035000e+09    NaN 4.370000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN -7.400000e+07   NaN 4.980000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.900000e+07    NaN 8.090000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 1.215000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.233000e+09    NaN 4.860000e+08    NaN 1.411894e+10    NaN -2.540000e+08   NaN NaN NaN
219538  219538  AAPL.US 2020-09-30  2020-10-30  USD 3.238880e+11    NaN NaN 1.126400e+10    2.585490e+11    6.533900e+10    NaN 4.932700e+10    5.077900e+10    1.496600e+10    4.610800e+10    NaN 3.395200e+10    3.801600e+10    1.053920e+11    1.376900e+10    1.376900e+10    1.124360e+11    -4.060000e+08   4.533600e+10    1.437130e+11    1.008870e+11    6.533900e+10    5.292700e+10    3.744500e+10    9.866700e+10    4.061000e+09    4.229600e+10    NaN NaN NaN -4.060000e+08   NaN 5.077900e+10    NaN 1.496600e+10    NaN NaN 4.252200e+10    NaN 1.801750e+11    NaN 9.866700e+10    5.449000e+10    1.531570e+11    NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.238880e+11    9.094300e+10    3.676600e+10    NaN 1.752821e+10    3.832100e+10    7.442000e+10    1.777750e+11    NaN NaN
```

Then this dataframe:

```
financials_Income_Statement_yearly.loc[financials_Income_Statement_yearly.ticker == 'AAPL.US']

Unnamed: 0  ticker  date    filing_date currency_symbol researchdevelopment effectofaccountingcharges   incomebeforetax minorityinterest    netincome   sellinggeneraladministrative    grossprofit ebit    nonoperatingincomenetother  operatingincome otheroperatingexpenses  interestexpense taxprovision    interestincome  netinterestincome   extraordinaryitems  nonrecurring    otheritems  incometaxexpense    totalrevenue    totaloperatingexpenses  costofrevenue   totalotherincomeexpensenet  discontinuedoperations  netincomefromcontinuingops  netincomeapplicabletocommonshares   preferredstockandotheradjustments   sellingandmarketingexpenses reconcileddepreciation  ebitda  depreciationandamortization
21731   21731   AAPL.US 2000-09-30  2000-12-14  USD 3.800000e+08    NaN 1.092000e+09    NaN 7.860000e+08    1.166000e+09    2.166000e+09    1.113000e+09    NaN 6.200000e+08    7.363000e+09    2.100000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.060000e+08    7.983000e+09    1.546000e+09    5.817000e+09    -4.720000e+08   NaN NaN 7.860000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 1.197000e+09    8.400000e+07
29898   29898   AAPL.US 2020-09-30  2020-10-30  USD 1.875200e+10    NaN 6.709100e+10    NaN 5.741100e+10    1.991600e+10    1.049560e+11    6.996400e+10    NaN 6.628800e+10    2.082270e+11    2.873000e+09    9.680000e+09    3.763000e+09    8.900000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 9.680000e+09    2.745150e+11    3.866800e+10    1.695590e+11    -8.030000e+08   NaN 5.741100e+10    5.741100e+10    NaN NaN 1.105600e+10    8.102000e+10    1.105600e+10
29924   29924   AAPL.US 2016-09-30  2016-10-26  USD 1.004500e+10    NaN 6.137200e+10    NaN 4.568700e+10    1.419400e+10    8.426300e+10    6.282800e+10    1.348000e+09    6.002400e+10    1.556150e+11    1.456000e+09    1.568500e+10    3.999000e+09    2.543000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.568500e+10    2.156390e+11    2.423900e+10    1.313760e+11    -1.348000e+09   NaN 4.568700e+10    4.568700e+10    NaN NaN NaN 7.333300e+10    1.050500e+10
29949   29949   AAPL.US 2012-09-30  2012-10-31  USD 3.381000e+09    NaN 5.576300e+10    NaN 4.173300e+10    1.004000e+10    6.866200e+10    5.576300e+10    5.220000e+08    5.524100e+10    1.012670e+11    0.000000e+00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.403000e+10    1.565080e+11    1.342100e+10    8.784600e+10    -5.220000e+08   NaN 4.173300e+10    4.173300e+10    NaN NaN NaN 5.904000e+10    3.277000e+09
29957   29957   AAPL.US 2005-09-30  2005-12-01  USD 5.340000e+08    NaN 1.815000e+09    NaN 1.335000e+09    1.859000e+09    4.043000e+09    1.815000e+09    NaN 1.650000e+09    1.228100e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.800000e+08    1.393100e+10    2.393000e+09    9.888000e+09    -1.650000e+08   NaN NaN 1.335000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.994000e+09    1.790000e+08
29980   29980   AAPL.US 1992-09-30  1992-09-30  NaN NaN NaN 8.555000e+08    NaN 5.304000e+08    2.289400e+09    3.312300e+09    8.555000e+08    NaN 8.057000e+08    6.280800e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.251000e+08    7.086500e+09    2.506600e+09    3.774200e+09    -4.980000e+07   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.072700e+09    2.172000e+08
29990   29990   AAPL.US 1991-09-30  1991-09-30  NaN NaN NaN 4.997000e+08    NaN 3.098000e+08    2.547400e+09    3.199100e+09    4.997000e+08    NaN 4.473000e+08    5.861500e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.899000e+08    6.308800e+09    2.751800e+09    3.109700e+09    -5.240000e+07   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.041000e+08    2.044000e+08
30011   30011   AAPL.US 1985-09-30  1985-09-30  NaN NaN NaN 1.200000e+08    NaN 6.120000e+07    6.532000e+08    8.423000e+08    1.200000e+08    NaN 1.473000e+08    1.771000e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.880000e+07    1.918300e+09    6.950000e+08    1.076000e+09    2.730000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.618000e+08    4.180000e+07
97600   97600   AAPL.US 2019-09-30  2019-10-31  USD 1.621700e+10    NaN 6.573700e+10    NaN 5.525600e+10    1.824500e+10    9.839200e+10    6.931300e+10    1.807000e+09    6.393000e+10    1.962440e+11    3.576000e+09    1.048100e+10    4.961000e+09    1.385000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.048100e+10    2.601740e+11    3.446200e+10    1.617820e+11    -1.807000e+09   NaN 5.525600e+10    5.525600e+10    NaN NaN 1.254700e+10    8.186000e+10    1.254700e+10
97645   97645   AAPL.US 2017-09-30  2017-11-03  USD 1.158100e+10    NaN 6.408900e+10    NaN 4.835100e+10    1.526100e+10    8.818600e+10    6.641200e+10    2.745000e+09    6.134400e+10    1.678900e+11    2.323000e+09    1.573800e+10    5.201000e+09    2.878000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 1.573800e+10    2.292340e+11    2.684200e+10    1.410480e+11    -2.745000e+09   NaN 4.835100e+10    4.835100e+10    NaN NaN 1.015700e+10    7.656900e+10    1.015700e+10
97680   97680   AAPL.US 2015-09-30  2015-10-28  USD 8.067000e+09    NaN 7.251500e+10    NaN 5.339400e+10    1.432900e+10    9.362600e+10    7.324800e+10    1.285000e+09    7.123000e+10    1.624850e+11    7.330000e+08    1.912100e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.912100e+10    2.337150e+11    2.239600e+10    1.400890e+11    -1.285000e+09   NaN 5.339400e+10    5.339400e+10    NaN NaN NaN 8.450500e+10    1.125700e+10
97709   97709   AAPL.US 2014-09-30  2014-10-27  USD 6.041000e+09    NaN 5.348300e+10    NaN 3.951000e+10    1.199300e+10    7.053700e+10    5.386700e+10    9.800000e+08    5.250300e+10    1.302920e+11    3.840000e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.397300e+10    1.827950e+11    1.803400e+10    1.122580e+11    -9.800000e+08   NaN 3.951000e+10    3.951000e+10    NaN NaN NaN 6.181300e+10    7.946000e+09
97728   97728   AAPL.US 2011-09-30  2011-10-26  USD 2.429000e+09    NaN 3.420500e+10    NaN 2.592200e+10    7.599000e+09    4.381800e+10    3.420500e+10    4.150000e+08    3.379000e+10    7.445900e+10    0.000000e+00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.283000e+09    1.082490e+11    1.002800e+10    6.443100e+10    -4.150000e+08   NaN 2.592200e+10    2.592200e+10    NaN NaN NaN 3.601900e+10    1.814000e+09
97750   97750   AAPL.US 2010-09-30  2010-10-27  USD 1.782000e+09    NaN 1.854000e+10    NaN 1.401300e+10    5.517000e+09    2.568400e+10    1.854000e+10    1.550000e+08    1.838500e+10    4.684000e+10    0.000000e+00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.527000e+09    6.522500e+10    7.299000e+09    3.954100e+10    -1.550000e+08   NaN 1.401300e+10    1.401300e+10    NaN NaN NaN 1.956700e+10    1.027000e+09
97778   97778   AAPL.US 2009-09-30  2009-10-27  USD 1.333000e+09    NaN 7.984000e+09    NaN 5.704000e+09    4.149000e+09    1.314000e+10    7.984000e+09    3.260000e+08    7.658000e+09    2.887900e+10    0.000000e+00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.280000e+09    3.653700e+10    5.482000e+09    2.339700e+10    -3.260000e+08   NaN 8.235000e+09    8.235000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 8.718000e+09    7.340000e+08
97785   97785   AAPL.US 2008-09-30  2008-11-05  USD 1.109000e+09    NaN 6.895000e+09    NaN 4.834000e+09    3.761000e+09    1.114500e+10    6.895000e+09    NaN 6.275000e+09    2.620400e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.061000e+09    3.247900e+10    4.870000e+09    2.133400e+10    -6.200000e+08   NaN NaN 4.834000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 7.368000e+09    4.730000e+08
97808   97808   AAPL.US 2007-09-30  2007-11-15  USD 7.820000e+08    NaN 5.008000e+09    NaN 3.496000e+09    2.963000e+09    8.154000e+09    5.008000e+09    NaN 4.409000e+09    1.959700e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.512000e+09    2.400600e+10    3.745000e+09    1.585200e+10    -5.990000e+08   NaN NaN 3.496000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 5.325000e+09    3.170000e+08
97833   97833   AAPL.US 2004-09-30  2004-12-03  USD 4.890000e+08    NaN 3.830000e+08    NaN 2.760000e+08    1.421000e+09    2.259000e+09    3.860000e+08    NaN 3.490000e+08    7.930000e+09    3.000000e+06    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.070000e+08    8.279000e+09    1.910000e+09    6.020000e+09    -3.400000e+07   NaN NaN 2.760000e+08    NaN NaN NaN 5.360000e+08    1.500000e+08
97844   97844   AAPL.US 2003-09-30  2003-12-19  USD 4.710000e+08    NaN 9.200000e+07    NaN 6.900000e+07    1.212000e+09    1.708000e+09    1.010000e+08    NaN 2.500000e+07    6.182000e+09    8.000000e+06    NaN NaN NaN 1.000000e+06    NaN NaN 2.400000e+07    6.207000e+09    1.683000e+09    4.499000e+09    -6.700000e+07   NaN NaN 6.800000e+07    NaN NaN NaN 2.140000e+08    1.130000e+08
97866   97866   AAPL.US 2002-09-30  2002-12-19  USD 4.470000e+08    NaN 8.700000e+07    NaN 6.500000e+07    1.111000e+09    1.603000e+09    9.800000e+07    NaN 4.500000e+07    5.697000e+09    1.100000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.200000e+07    5.742000e+09    1.558000e+09    4.139000e+09    -4.200000e+07   NaN NaN 6.500000e+07    NaN NaN NaN 2.120000e+08    1.140000e+08
97876   97876   AAPL.US 2001-09-30  2001-12-21  USD 4.410000e+08    NaN -5.200000e+07   NaN -2.500000e+07   1.138000e+09    1.235000e+09    -2.400000e+07   NaN -3.440000e+08   5.707000e+09    1.600000e+07    NaN NaN NaN 1.200000e+07    NaN NaN -1.500000e+07   5.363000e+09    1.579000e+09    4.128000e+09    -2.920000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.600000e+07    1.000000e+08
97903   97903   AAPL.US 1999-09-30  1999-12-22  NaN 3.140000e+08    NaN 6.760000e+08    NaN 6.010000e+08    9.960000e+08    1.696000e+09    7.230000e+08    NaN 3.860000e+08    5.748000e+09    4.700000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.500000e+07    6.134000e+09    1.310000e+09    4.438000e+09    -2.900000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.080000e+08    8.500000e+07
97910   97910   AAPL.US 1998-09-30  1998-09-25  NaN 3.100000e+08    NaN 3.290000e+08    NaN 3.090000e+08    9.080000e+08    1.479000e+09    3.910000e+08    NaN 2.610000e+08    5.680000e+09    6.200000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.000000e+07    5.941000e+09    1.218000e+09    4.462000e+09    -6.800000e+07   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.020000e+08    1.110000e+08
97935   97935   AAPL.US 1996-09-30  1996-12-19  NaN 6.040000e+08    NaN -1.295000e+09   NaN -8.160000e+08   1.568000e+09    9.680000e+08    -1.235000e+09   NaN -1.204000e+09   1.103700e+10    6.000000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN -4.790000e+08   9.833000e+09    2.172000e+09    8.865000e+09    9.100000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN -1.079000e+09   1.560000e+08
97942   97942   AAPL.US 1995-09-30  1995-12-19  NaN 6.140000e+08    NaN 6.740000e+08    NaN 4.240000e+08    1.583000e+09    2.858000e+09    7.220000e+08    NaN 6.610000e+08    1.040100e+10    4.800000e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.500000e+08    1.106200e+10    2.197000e+09    8.204000e+09    -1.300000e+07   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.490000e+08    1.270000e+08
97951   97951   AAPL.US 1994-09-30  1994-12-13  NaN 5.643030e+08    NaN 5.002860e+08    NaN 3.101780e+08    1.384111e+09    2.343833e+09    5.399390e+08    NaN 3.954190e+08    8.793329e+09    3.965300e+07    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.901080e+08    9.188748e+09    1.948414e+09    6.844915e+09    -1.048670e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.078970e+08    1.679580e+08
97971   97971   AAPL.US 1993-09-30  1993-09-30  NaN NaN NaN 1.397000e+08    NaN 8.660000e+07    2.617800e+09    2.894300e+09    1.397000e+08    NaN 1.104000e+08    7.866600e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.310000e+07    7.977000e+09    2.783900e+09    5.082700e+09    -2.930000e+07   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.058000e+08    1.661000e+08
98003   98003   AAPL.US 1990-09-30  1990-09-30  NaN NaN NaN 7.785000e+08    NaN 4.749000e+08    2.240200e+09    3.154900e+09    7.785000e+08    NaN 7.120000e+08    4.846400e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.036000e+08    5.558400e+09    2.442900e+09    2.403500e+09    -6.650000e+07   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 9.812000e+08    2.027000e+08
98013   98013   AAPL.US 1989-09-30  1989-09-30  NaN NaN NaN 7.443000e+08    NaN 4.540000e+08    1.954900e+09    2.714000e+09    7.443000e+08    NaN 6.343000e+08    4.649700e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.903000e+08    5.284000e+09    2.079700e+09    2.570000e+09    -1.100000e+08   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.691000e+08    1.248000e+08
98036   98036   AAPL.US 1987-09-30  1987-09-30  NaN NaN NaN 4.104000e+08    NaN 2.175000e+08    9.934000e+08    1.435400e+09    4.104000e+08    NaN 3.715000e+08    2.289600e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.929000e+08    2.661100e+09    1.063900e+09    1.225700e+09    -3.890000e+07   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.809000e+08    7.050000e+07
98047   98047   AAPL.US 1986-09-30  1986-09-30  NaN NaN NaN 3.098000e+08    NaN 1.540000e+08    7.373000e+08    1.061900e+09    3.098000e+08    NaN 2.735000e+08    1.628400e+09    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.558000e+08    1.901900e+09    7.884000e+08    8.400000e+08    -3.630000e+07   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.609000e+08    5.110000e+07
```

If I try to merge it:

```py
var = pd.concat([financials_Balance_Sheet_yearly, financials_Income_Statement_yearly], axis=1)
var = var.loc[var['ticker'] == 'AAPL.US']
var
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

When I tried merge, I got empty cells.

Basically ticker and date should be the keys to map all the other columns. If they don't match, then. it should keep the data and I'll assess the problem/clean it up.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the columns `'ticker'` and `'date'` present in both DataFrames are causing both the 'ticker' and 'date' columns to become multidimensional when you concatenate the DataFrames together.

When I run your original code, this is what `var['ticker']` looks like (and `var['date']` looks similar):

```
>>> var['ticker']
     ticker   ticker
0   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
1   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
2   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
3   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
4   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
5   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
6   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
7   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
8   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
9   AAPL.US  AAPL.US
10  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
11  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
12  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
13  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
14  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
15  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
16  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
17  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
18  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
19  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
20  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
21  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
22  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
23  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
24  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
25  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
26  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
27  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
28  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
29  AAPL.US  AAPL.US
30      NaN  AAPL.US
```

One solution could be to set the `ticker` and `date` columns to the be index before concatenating the DataFrames, then reset the index:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index(['ticker','date']),df2.set_index(['ticker','date'])],axis=1).reset_index()
```

```
     ticker        date  Unnamed:         0 filing_date currency_symbol  ...  netincomeapplicabletocommonshares  preferredstockandotheradjustments  sellingandmarketingexpenses  reconcileddepreciation        ebitda  depreciationandamortization
0   AAPL.US  1985-09-30  128846.0  128846.0  1985-09-30             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  1.618000e+08                 4.180000e+07
1   AAPL.US  1986-09-30  193123.0  193123.0  1986-09-30             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  3.609000e+08                 5.110000e+07
2   AAPL.US  1987-09-30       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  4.809000e+08                 7.050000e+07
3   AAPL.US  1988-09-30  128805.0  128805.0  1988-09-30             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN           NaN                          NaN
4   AAPL.US  1989-09-30  128810.0  128810.0  1989-09-30             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  8.691000e+08                 1.248000e+08
5   AAPL.US  1990-09-30  128765.0  128765.0  1990-09-30             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  9.812000e+08                 2.027000e+08
6   AAPL.US  1991-09-30  128753.0  128753.0  1991-09-30             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  7.041000e+08                 2.044000e+08
7   AAPL.US  1992-09-30  128748.0  128748.0  1992-09-30             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  1.072700e+09                 2.172000e+08
8   AAPL.US  1993-09-30  145183.0  145183.0  1993-09-30             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  3.058000e+08                 1.661000e+08
9   AAPL.US  1994-09-30  128720.0  128720.0  1994-12-13             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  7.078970e+08                 1.679580e+08
10  AAPL.US  1995-09-30       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  8.490000e+08                 1.270000e+08
11  AAPL.US  1996-09-30  128713.0  128713.0  1996-12-19             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN -1.079000e+09                 1.560000e+08
12  AAPL.US  1997-09-30  214345.0  214345.0  1997-12-05             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN           NaN                          NaN
13  AAPL.US  1998-09-30  128698.0  128698.0  1998-09-25             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  5.020000e+08                 1.110000e+08
14  AAPL.US  1999-09-30  128684.0  128684.0  1999-12-22             NaN  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  8.080000e+08                 8.500000e+07
15  AAPL.US  2000-09-30  128694.0  128694.0  2000-12-14             USD  ...                       7.860000e+08                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  1.197000e+09                 8.400000e+07
16  AAPL.US  2001-09-30  128670.0  128670.0  2001-12-21             USD  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  7.600000e+07                 1.000000e+08
17  AAPL.US  2002-09-30  128621.0  128621.0  2002-12-19             USD  ...                       6.500000e+07                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  2.120000e+08                 1.140000e+08
18  AAPL.US  2003-09-30       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN  ...                       6.800000e+07                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  2.140000e+08                 1.130000e+08
19  AAPL.US  2004-09-30  128610.0  128610.0  2004-12-03             USD  ...                       2.760000e+08                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  5.360000e+08                 1.500000e+08
20  AAPL.US  2005-09-30  128588.0  128588.0  2005-12-01             USD  ...                       1.335000e+09                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  1.994000e+09                 1.790000e+08
21  AAPL.US  2006-09-30  128581.0  128581.0  2006-12-29             USD  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN           NaN                          NaN
22  AAPL.US  2007-09-30       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN  ...                       3.496000e+09                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  5.325000e+09                 3.170000e+08
23  AAPL.US  2008-09-30  128550.0  128550.0  2008-11-05             USD  ...                       4.834000e+09                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  7.368000e+09                 4.730000e+08
24  AAPL.US  2009-09-30       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN  ...                       8.235000e+09                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  8.718000e+09                 7.340000e+08
25  AAPL.US  2010-09-30  128514.0  128514.0  2010-10-27             USD  ...                       1.401300e+10                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  1.956700e+10                 1.027000e+09
26  AAPL.US  2011-09-30  128453.0  128453.0  2011-10-26             USD  ...                       2.592200e+10                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  3.601900e+10                 1.814000e+09
27  AAPL.US  2012-09-30  128450.0  128450.0  2012-10-31             USD  ...                       4.173300e+10                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  5.904000e+10                 3.277000e+09
28  AAPL.US  2013-09-30  128413.0  128413.0  2013-10-30             USD  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN           NaN                          NaN
29  AAPL.US  2014-09-30  128386.0  128386.0  2014-10-27             USD  ...                       3.951000e+10                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  6.181300e+10                 7.946000e+09
30  AAPL.US  2015-09-30       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN  ...                       5.339400e+10                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  8.450500e+10                 1.125700e+10
31  AAPL.US  2016-09-30  128337.0  128337.0  2016-10-26             USD  ...                       4.568700e+10                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN  7.333300e+10                 1.050500e+10
32  AAPL.US  2017-09-30  128311.0  128311.0  2017-11-03             USD  ...                       4.835100e+10                                NaN                          NaN            1.015700e+10  7.656900e+10                 1.015700e+10
33  AAPL.US  2018-09-30  128288.0  128288.0  2018-11-05             USD  ...                                NaN                                NaN                          NaN                     NaN           NaN                          NaN
34  AAPL.US  2019-09-30  128270.0  128270.0  2019-10-31             USD  ...                       5.525600e+10                                NaN                          NaN            1.254700e+10  8.186000e+10                 1.254700e+10
35  AAPL.US  2020-09-30  219538.0  219538.0  2020-10-30             USD  ...                       5.741100e+10                                NaN                          NaN            1.105600e+10  8.102000e+10                 1.105600e+10

[36 rows x 100 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much it looks like its working. I have to do this for almost every dataframe I think(I have over 30 dataframes I'm merging!!). 

If I just do this df1 = df1.set_index(['ticker','date']) before hand then it'll work also I think?

Comment: @Lostsoul yeah you can definitely do that too if you are okay with changing the original objects